# Programming Contests on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, contest

Its no wonder that Stack Overflow has a vast community of great and enthusiastic programmers. Don't you think Stack Overflow should be organizing  weekly or monthly programming contests/challenges for added zeal among its users?

Comment: You think there isn't enough zeal already?

Comment: Programmers had a [contest](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3546/programmers-se-contest-the-complete-outline) and it went really well. :)

Comment: There are dedicated SE sites for people having enough time and a mind for these games, like [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/?as=1). Isn't that enough ?

Comment: CodeGolf !! I really wasnt aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: The primary goal of most contests is to drive traffic to the smaller SE sites, and SO's doesn't really need more traffic - it's already the go-to site for code questions. Perhaps a contest related to something else, such as answering unanswered questions, or editing/cleaning up the site might work...

Comment: BTW, Saurabh, we'd love to have you on CodeGolf, but please do read our FAQ and look around a bit before you post...our rules catch some people by surprise. *::doffs CodeGolf.SE moderator hat::*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Doing a code contest is a very different thing from helping programmers solve specific problems in their coding.

I think that SO is best at remaining focused on its task and that those events should be strongly separated or simply the goal of specific SE sites like [CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/?as=1).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Code Golf site.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this kind of thing would be well-suited for [codegolf.stackexchange.com](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) (currently in beta, at the time of this posting).

Below is a brief excerpt from the [FAQ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq):

---

### [What kind of questions can I ask here?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

*Programming Puzzles & Code Golf* is for programming puzzles and code golf, anywhere in skill from beginner to expert.

*Code golf* is a special type of programming puzzle where the shortest correct code submission wins.

- Code length is usually counted in characters (Unicode code points),
  though some contests use bytes.
- In no case is the length counted in terms of number of words, lines, etc.

All **questions** on this site, whether a programming puzzle or a code golf, should have …

- An *objective* primary winning criterion, so that it is possible to indisputably decide which entry should win.
- A clear specification of what constitutes a *correct* submission. Test cases are highly encouraged.
- "Tips for golfing in *some language*"-type posts are an exception to this rule. Such posts are community wiki and do not collect reputation.
- These questions are surprisingly hard to write well. Help may be available on the [Puzzle Lab chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/307) or the [meta Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/423/78), and the use of these resources is encouraged.

All **answers** to standard questions should …

- Correctly implement the required specification.
- Be a serious contender for the winning criteria in use. For example, an entry to a code golf contest needs to be golfed (see below), and an entry to a speed contest needs to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Generally these kind of contests are a way for firms to recruit someone, which gives them a platform on whom(candidates) to bet on. I dont think SO needs this & their way of serving is being a forum and all they need is moderators apart from their core developing team.

Comment: Not really. Take a look at some of the earlier contests. ([Gaming.SE], e.g.)